# php imagecopyresampled not working as expected

Tags: php, image, php-gd

I am trying to crop images using `imagecopyresampled` before saving them to a ftp-server.

My php is:

```
function image_resizing($image, $type, $ext, $quality, $file_name) {
    strtolower($ext);
    list($src_width, $src_height) = getimagesize($image);
    switch($ext) {
        case 'gif':
        $image_create = 'imagecreatefromgif';
        break;

        case 'png':
        $image_create = 'imagecreatefrompng';
        break;

        default:
        $image_create = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
        break;        
    } 

    $temp_img = $image_create($image);

    if($type == 'wide') {
        $width = 1920;
        $height = 2160;
    } else if($type == 'content') {
        $height = 600;
        $width = 400;
    }

    $src_x = ($src_width - $width) / 2;
    $src_y = ($src_height - $height) / 2;

    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled ($new_image, $temp_img, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $width, $height, $src_width, $src_height);
    $image_dest = '';
    imagejpeg($new_image, $file_name, $quality);
}
```

But somehow I keep ending up with black space around my cropped area or all black (in the smaller image) in the new image. As far as I can see the src/dest coordinates are correct.

images:

http://www.strongleaf.nl/images/website_images/content-images/image-test-image-imagecopyresampled.jpg

http://www.strongleaf.nl/images/website_images/wide-images/image-test-image-imagecopyresampled.jpg

Comment: Is the original image bigger than the dimensions you hardcoded in the code (1920x2160 or 600x400) ?

Comment: Yes it is bigger. And with different dimensions (for the destination image) I get similar results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the original image is bigger, I think the pb is that the last two parameters of imagecopyresampled delimit a rectangle outside the original image. Can you try :

```
imagecopyresampled ($new_image, $temp_img, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $width, $height, $width, $height);
```

Comment: Great! That's it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I see few problems:

1) you should change imagecopyresampled to (note last two params)

```
imagecopyresampled ($new_image, $temp_img, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $width, $height, $width, $height);
```

2) you should have

```
$ext = strtolower($ext);
```

3) $width, $height gonna be zero in case you have wrong $type passed into the function

---

But still you won't avoid black space around images which have different proportions then 1920x2160 or 400x600, if they are smaller in any dimension.

I do recommend do not bother with [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php). Use [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) instead.

You can call [::cropthumbnailimage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropthumbnailimage.php) in Imagick, which will solve all problems with dimensions. Main reason I started using Imagick was really high memory usage of GD library.